# Matching reversible pairs in a CSV file

Tags: awk, perl

I have a .csv file which looks like this:

```
A,B,1999
C,D,1990
B,A,1989
D,A,1990
A,B,1999
...
```

I want to rearrange it to look roughly like this:

```
A,B,1989,0,B,A,1
A,B,1999,2,B,A,0
C,D,1990,1,D,C,0
D,A,1990,1,A,D,0
```

In other words, I'd like to have the number of times the pair `A,B` occurs for each of the values recorded in the third column, and also the number of times `B,A` occur for the same value.

I'm mostly struggling with matching the lines that say `A,B` with the ones that say `B,A`.

Would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: there's no such record `A,B,1989` within the input file. I would suggest to output `B,A,1989,1,A,B,0` instead of `A,B,1989,0,B,A,1`

Comment: Is there a way to have all `A,B`s in either columns 1 and 2 or 5,6, though? That would help me greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -F',' '{ k=$1 FS $2 }{ a[k][$3]++; rev[k]=$2 FS $1 }
           END{ 
               for(i in a) 
                   for(j in a[i]) { 
                       print i, j, a[i][j], rev[i], a[rev[i]][j]+0; 
                       delete a[rev[i]][j] 
                   }
           }' OFS=',' file
```

The output:

```
C,D,1990,1,D,C,0
A,B,1999,2,B,A,0
D,A,1990,1,A,D,0
B,A,1989,1,A,B,0
```

Answer (score 0):

This one in Perl seems to be working.

```
perl -F, -alne '
    next if /^\s*$/;
    $hs{$F[2]}{"$F[0],$F[1]"}++;
    END{
        while (my ($nr, $lhs) = each %hs) {
            while (my ($lts, $cnt) = each %{$lhs}) {
                my $rvs = scalar reverse $lts;
                my $rvsn = $hs{$nr}{$rvs} // 0;
                print "$lts,$nr,$cnt,$rvs,$rvsn";
                delete $hs{$nr}{$rvs};
            }
        }
    }
' data
```

Explained line by line:

1. Run Perl with `,` **f**or delimiter, read fields into an **a**rray, take care of **l**ine endings, run for each li**n**e, and **e**xecute:

   ```
   perl -F, -alne '
   ```
2. Skip blank lines in input:

   ```
   next if /^\s*$/;
   ```
3. Increase the hash counter for each record:

   ```
   $hs{$F[2]}{"$F[0],$F[1]"}++;
   ```
4. Start the final block:

   ```
   END{
   ```
5. Read the hash:

   ```
   while (my ($nr, $lhs) = each %hs) {
       while (my ($lts, $cnt) = each %{$lhs}) {
   ```
6. Prepare data for printing:

   ```
   my $rvs = scalar reverse $lts;
   my $rvsn = $hs{$nr}{$rvs} // 0;
   print "$lts,$nr,$cnt,$rvs,$rvsn";
   ```
7. Get rid of the twin entry in the hash:

   ```
   delete $hs{$nr}{$rvs};
   ```
8. `data` is the input file.

As a result, for this input data:

```
A,B,1999
C,D,1990
B,A,1989
D,A,1990
A,B,1999
B,A,1999
```

you should get this output:

```
D,A,1990,1,A,D,0
C,D,1990,1,D,C,0
B,A,1989,1,A,B,0
A,B,1999,2,B,A,1
```